# Angular 2 with Webpack: Can't access libraries in vendors file

Tags: angular, webpack

My Angular 2.0.2 app uses Webpack. I have a `vendors.ts` file where I import external JavaScript that I would like to use.

Example (in vendors.ts):

```
import '../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js';
```

After doing this, my vendor bundle file contains "Moment JS" code, but I can't use it in my application.

It says:

> momentjs is required with dateFormat. please add "> in your html.
>   EXCEPTION: moment is not defined

If I manually add a reference to the script tag in my `index.html` file, everything works. I have the same problem for all externally loaded libraries, not just "Moment JS".

This is my entire webpack config:

```
// Core stuff
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
var ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

// Get NPM lifecycle event to identify the environment
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {

// This is the object where all configuration gets set
var config = {};

// Devltool (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool)
// Type of sourcemap to use per build type
if (isProd) {

config.devtool = 'source-map';

} else if (isTest) {

config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';

}
else {

config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';

}

// Entry (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry)
config.entry = isTest ? {} : { 
'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts', 
'vendor': './src/vendor.ts', 
'app': './src/main.ts' 
};

// Output (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output)
config.output = isTest ? {} : {
path: root('dist'),
publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:3000/',
filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
};

// Resolve (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve)
config.resolve = {
extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'], // Only discover files that have those extensions
 };

var atlOptions = '';
if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false'; // "awesome-typescript-loader" needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps
}

// Loaders (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders)
config.module = {
rules: [

  // Support for TypeScript (.ts) files
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      'awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 
      'angular2-template-loader', 
      '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
      'angular2-router-loader'
    ],
    exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
  },

  // Copy assets to output
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'
  },

  // Support for *.json files.
  {
    test: /\.json$/, 
    loader: 'json'
  },

  // Support for CSS as raw text
  // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
  // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: root('src', 'app'),
    loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css', 'postcss']})
  },


  // support for .scss files
  // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
  // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: root('src', 'app'),
    loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: ['css', 'postcss', 'sassLoader']})
  },

  // Support for .html as raw text
  {
    test: /\.html$/, 
    loader: 'raw',  
    exclude: root('src', 'public')
  }

  ]
  };

  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
  // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
  config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.ts$/,
  enforce: 'post',
  include: path.resolve('src'),
  loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
  exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
  });
  }

  if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
  // tslint support
  config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.ts$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  loader: 'tslint'
  });
  }

  // Plugins (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins)
  config.plugins = [

 // Define env variables to help with builds (https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin)
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
  }
 }),

 // Workaround needed for Angular 2 (angular/angular#11580)
 new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/, root('./src')),

 // Tslint configuration for Webpack 2
 new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  options: {

    // Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader (https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader)
    tslint: {
      emitErrors: false,
      failOnHint: false
    },

    // Sass (https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader)
    sassLoader: {
      //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
    },

    //PostCSS (https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core)
    postcss: [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 version']
      })
    ]

  }
}),

new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery'
})

];

if (!isTest && !isProd) {
  config.plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());
}

if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
config.plugins.push(

  new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

  // Generate common chunks if necessary (https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html - https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin)
  new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
  }),

  // Inject script and link tags into html files (https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/public/index.html',
    chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
  }),

  // Extract css files (https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin)
  new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css', disable: !isProd})

 );
 }

 // Add build specific plugins
if (isProd) {
config.plugins.push(

  // Only emit files when there are no errors (http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin)
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

  // Dedupe modules in the output (http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin)
  // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

  // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode (http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin)
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true, 
    mangle: { 
      keep_fnames: true 
    }
  }),

  // Copy assets from the public folder (https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin)
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
    from: root('src/public')
  }])

);
}

// Dev server configuration (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver - http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)
config.devServer = {
contentBase: './src/public',
historyApiFallback: true,
quiet: true,
stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
};

return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't need to add the `node_modules` folder in the vendors.ts file.

Use do: `moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js`

Also, you're Webpack config doesn't really seem to be in order. I'm seeing no `.entry` or `.resolve` etc..

Maybe you should try some Angular webpack starters:

- [Angular Class](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)
- [Qdouble](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter)

Comment: Imported without "node_modules" folder but the result is the same. Entry and resolve IS in the webpack config (`config.resolve` and `config.entry`) and I am using a starter template. This config comes from https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack